# python loop appending everything

Tags: python, loops

The following code is appending every iteration to the next. Every file should be about 50 players but filename team 1 is 50 and filename team 2 is 100(team1 + team2) and so on. How can I create the individual file with only the 1 iteration of year+team.

```
from nfl_fun import make_soup
import os
from itertools import islice
import csv
from datetime import datetime

years = [2019,2018,2017,2016,2015]

year = datetime.now().year

if year not in years:
    years.append(year)

linkname = ""


with open("teamlink.csv") as tl:

    for row in islice(csv.reader(tl), 1, None):
        for season in years:
            rowlink = f"https://www.footballdb.com/{row[0]}/roster/{season}"
            soup = make_soup(rowlink)
            try:
                for boot in soup.findAll('b'):

                    for link in boot.findAll('a'):

                        if link.has_attr('href'):
                            linkname = linkname + "\n" + (link.attrs['href'])[1:]

                            userfile = f"{rowlink[37:-12]}-{season}"
                            header="Links"
                            file = open(os.path.expanduser(f"{userfile}.csv"), "wb")
                            file.write(bytes(header, encoding="ascii", errors='ignore'))
                            file.write(bytes(linkname, encoding="ascii",errors='ignore'))
                            file.close()

            except:
                continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset `linkname` every time you change team, you can just add

```
linkname = ""
```

after `file.close()` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that hours before and then it was only writing 1 name to each file. But before I responded I tried your solution again and it worked. FML Thanks again

Comment: sometimes you need another pair of eye and with multiple nested for is easy to get confused